# Upstart cannot determine daemon's pid

Tags: python, upstart, services

There is a daemon `mydaemon`, which has not a very pleasant interface. So that `mydaemon-parser.py` was written to parse configuration files and start as many `mydaemon` instances as needed. `mydaemon-parser.py` use `subprocess.call()` to call external commands. I found out that `mydaemon-parser.py` forked 16 times to start one `mydaemon` instance.
How is upstart supposed to determine `mydaemon` pids.
I want to use upstart because `mydaemon` is not a very stable product. I am tired to start it after it fails.
May be there is a better way to keep the service up?

Comment: Have a try with the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12200217/2530240) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @edwin thank you! Did not expect to find the answer (though not very good for me :) on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of the above mentioned answer says, that solution is an "ugly hack". Have a look at the [Upstart Cookbook -- instance](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#instance) section and see if you can create a .conf file for individual instances of mydaemon. Then when you run mydaemon-parser.py, use

`subprocess.call('initctl start mydaemon INST="SomeNewInstance"')`

The python code will have to find a way to identify a unique value for "SomeNewInstance".

You can then have a pidless wrapper job that runs mydaemon-parser.py probably in a `pre-start script`. This job will have the `start on` and `stop on` stanzas.

The problem then would be stopping the instances. The cookbook has suggestions for this. Pay special attention to the section entitled '6.14.2 Another Instance Example', and the code block immediately preceeding that which suggests the following as an example:

```
initctl list | grep "^foo " | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1 | while read i
do
  sudo stop foo BAR="$i"
done
```

I'm going to post a similar set of jobs I made to start/stop PostgreSQL clusters through Upstart. When I do, I'll add a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225018/postgresql-configuring-as-upstart-job-problem/414337#414337) to it here because it provides some pretty good examples.