# What is the easiest way to create a meta upstart script

Tags: upstart

I want to have a "meta" upstart service that start/stops several other upstart services.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do this for multiple PostgreSQL instances along with their pgagent instances. Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225018/postgresql-configuring-as-upstart-job-problem/414337#414337) answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have a single script always start/stop the same scripts, you could just include all of those scripts directly in the original (single) script.  If the other scripts don't need to be Upstart scripts (if they're executable scripts or binaries) then another option is to have a single shell script that starts them in the background, and the single Upstart script would stop them when it shuts down.