# Running a daemon process from upstart

Tags: 12.04, boot, upstart, process, restart

I'm running my application on a VPS under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

And I have a problem with one daemon process for one of my applications.
This process is called "delayed_job" (If not familiar - this is just a background task handler).

The problem with this process is that sometimes it gets killed (I suppose it is because I have limited amount of RAM on my server - only 1GB).

But the main problem with this thing is that it is **not capable** of booting again after a crash or "kill" signal, unlike "unicorn" (it is a Rails app server) processes, which are always getting re-booted no matter what happens to them.

And yes, this IS a very big deal, because a lot of application features are using background tasks.

Same story happens when there are maintenance works on the VPS (initiated by the owner of the VPS) and after the restart the "delayed_job" process is not present in the system anymore.

This is the command I run every single time to boot it up: `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`

It is a well-known problem, but the only solution I found on the Internet is this article: http://www.alexreisner.com/code/upstart that suggests using Linux's "upstart" feature with the "respawn" option that is capable of re-booting the process if it gets killed or crashed.

Even though the article is a bit out-dated, I found out that Ubuntu 12.04 should support this feature and I've created a symlink in `/etc/init` directory (I've called it: delayed_job.conf) to the "delayed_job" file that I'd put in one of my applications folders (app_name/config, to be exact) - I've done everything this article says.

My problem is: when I try booting this new process (`start delayed_job`) in the console I get:

```
delayed_job start/running, process 6000
```

But in fact - no "delayed_job" process is getting created at all.

And the status (`status delayed_job`) of the initctl process is still: `delayed_job stop/waiting`

After I execute `kill -9 6000` I get `-bash: kill: (6000) - No such process`

So, this means that nothing gets executed. I've tried running this numerous times under different conditions - nothing, no avail. Is simply does not work.

Is there any thing I could try to make it work, or it is just useless ?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your EXPECT stanza is incorrect or not there. Upstart is tracking the wrong pid. See the cookbook for instructions on how to use [EXPECT](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect). Note the warning about how important that section is to understand.

Note that if your application is too forky (meaning it forks more than twice) for Upstart to track its pid, you may be able to track it yourself. The app may have a mechanism to write a pid file, or you may be able to capture it with `start-stop-daemon`. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225018/postgresql-configuring-as-upstart-job-problem/414337#414337) answer for an example, specifically the pg_agent.conf file.

**Edit:**

Note, if Upstart can't track your app's pid, you won't be able to use the `RESPAWN` stanza. In this case Upstart may not suit your needs. Perhaps a competing product like `forever` will. Don't know.

Comment: Yeah. I did not use "expect" stanza at all. Thanks! I'll take a look!

Comment: Well, now the "start" and "stop" both work, but, the 'delayed_job' process is not booting-up (according to ps aux | grep "delayed_job"). 
I tried both options: fork and daemon - neither works.

Comment: What is the [fork count](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#how-to-establish-fork-count)?

Comment: should I count it using strace ?
What should I do if it is greater than 2 (deamon) ?

Comment: Yes, count with strace. See the last sentence of my edited answer for ideas if it's > 2.

Comment: Thank you! I won't be marking your answer as "accepted", I need to test it first :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I've re-read your edited answer.
Yes, there is an "pid" file mechanism - file is stored under /root/to/app/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid and this file contains only one line - PID, which actually corresponds to its real value (according to ps aux | grep "delayed_job"). 

I've tried reading the information from the link you provided, but since I'm a rookie - I didn't understand anything. How would I pass the "reference" to this file? What is the exact command (or sequence of commands) of passing the PID to the upstart to track?

Comment: Good, so you have the PID file. The "reference" is just the file name. Look at the post stop-script in the pg_agent.conf section of the link. Look at how `start-stop-daemon` is being used to stop a process with a PID file; it's very simple. Looks like you're not understanding 'too forky' applications. Upstart can't track their PIDs -- at all. You have to do it. The good news for you is your app creates a PID file, so you don't have to do anything to start it. You only have to handle stopping it. If you want me to give you the full syntax, post the full contents of `delayed_job.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 

My "conf" file contains only 3 rows right know:

expect daemon # I know this line is incorrect by now
exec /root/to/app/script/delayed_job start
respawn

Comment: Arrgh, sorry! i forgot the whole reason you're doing this is to get the RESPAWN functionality. That won't work unless Upstart tracks your pid, and your app is too forky. Looks like Upstart won't work for you. You might look into `forever` or a similar competing product. Sorry to waste both our time.

Comment: Oh. And even this: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/upstart/+spec/return-pid-from-exec 
will not work ? 
I'll take at "forever" then. Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge this feature is not available in mainstream Upstart yet. It's quite exciting though; it's exactly what it needs for cases like yours and my pg_agent.conf job. I'll see if I can find if it's available yet. If you beat me to it, please post here.

Comment: Using `strace` to count the number of `clone`/`fork` calls, the PID that `delayed_job` puts in its PID file is returned by the 301st `clone` call. So yeah, not gonna work with Upstart respawn...

Comment: Sigh, everything's going to Systemd now anyway. I'll have to re-do all of this.